# Rendering json in ruby on rails views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am in the process of learning ruby on rails,
I have a controller named **welcome_controller** and the controller has a **json object**, and I have a view named **index.html.haml**

How do I access that json object from the view

```
render 'index', :layout => false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

render json: @payment.to_json

Answer (score 0):

```
var my_var = JSON.parse(('<%= my_controller_json %>') 
console.log(JSON.stringify(my_var))
```

Put this in   of your index page 
for more info see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28870567/rails-4-passing-variables-to-javascript/28870878#28870878)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

`render json: @your_json_object`

Comment: this works but I need to render the view also
this would give me a double render error

Comment: `respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @your_json_object }
 end`

Comment: do I have to rename index.html.haml to index.erb