# Using data from Rails DB in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm developing web app using Ruby on Rails 7.0.
I tried to use data from DB created by rails in JS, but I got a error.
I'm a beginner, especially when it comes to backend.
I hope someone's help :)

- error
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5DOq.png)
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6omC3.png)
- index.html.erb

```
<p style="color: green"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Contents</h1>

<div id="contents" data-contents="<%= @contents.to_json %>"></div> 

<script>
var contentsHash = $('#contents').data('contents');
console.log(contentsHash[0].title);
</script>
```

- application.html.erb

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="h-100">
  <head>
    <title>MapTest</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js" integrity="sha256-JlqSTELeR4TLqP0OG9dxM7yDPqX1ox/HfgiSLBj8+kM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
  ...
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried to access data by getting attributes of div tag(id="contents").

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. Please, do not link images of your code, refer to the question guidelines here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: you will observe that the javascript variable `contentsHash` contains a string. So of course `contentsHash[0].title` will fail. You need to `JSON.parse(contentsHash)`

Answer (score 0):

For large sets of data, from a rails view to javascript, i use the gem Gon.

https://github.com/gazay/gon

It exists others solutions
[Rails 4: Passing variables to javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28870567/rails-4-passing-variables-to-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps do away with the DIV entirely, changing your `index.html` file to be:

```
<p style="color: green"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Contents</h1>

<script>
var contentsHash = <%= @contents.to_json.html_safe %>;
console.log(contentsHash[0].title);
</script>
```